# Swiift - Decoding json data from server

Tags: swift, generics

Im working on a project where I have to display data from a network call. The problem is Im having trouble decoding data the data that I received from the network call and storing it into structs variable to use for other calls. The deadline is coming close and Im not sure why my code does not work. This is json that I receive back

```
{"result":{"login":{"isAuthorized":true,"isEmpty":false,"userName":{"isEmpty":false,"name":{"firstName":"Jason","lastName":"Test","displayName":"Test, Jason","isEmpty":false,"fullName":"Jason Test"},"canDelete":false,"id":5793,"canModify":false},"username":"test@testable.com"},"parameters":{"isEmpty":false,"keep_logged_in_indicator":false,"username":"test@testable.com"}},"isAuthorized":true,"version":{"major":"2021","minor":"004","fix":"04","display":"2021.004.04","isEmpty":false},"isSystemDown":false,"timestamp":"2021-07-26T20:21:43Z","isSuccess":true}
```

This is the different struct that I made in my project

```
struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    let results: Results?
    let isAuthorized: Bool?
    let version: Version?
    let isSystemDown: Bool?
    let errors: [serverError]?
    let timestamp: Date?
    let isSuccess: Bool?
    
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Results: Decodable {
    let login: Login
    let parameters: Parameters?
}

// MARK: - Login
struct Login: Decodable {
    let isAuthorized, isEmpty: Bool?
    let userName: UserName
    let username: String?
}

// MARK: - UserName
struct UserName: Decodable {
    let isEmpty: Bool?
    let name: Name
    let canDelete: Bool?
    let id: Int
    let canModify: Bool?
}

// MARK: - Name
struct Name: Decodable {
    let firstName, lastName, displayName: String
    let isEmpty: Bool?
    let fullName: String
}

// MARK: - Parameters
struct Parameters: Decodable {
    let isEmpty, keepLoggedInIndicator: Bool?
    let username: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isEmpty
        case keepLoggedInIndicator
        case username
    }
}

// MARK: - Version
struct Version: Decodable {
    let major, minor, fix, display: String?
    let isEmpty: Bool?
}

// Mark: - Error
struct serverError: Decodable {
    let password: String?
}
```

The code that I am using to decode the json data is this

```
private func handleResponse<T: Decodable>(result: Result<Data, Error>?, completion: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let result = result else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
        
        switch result {
        
            case .success(let data):
                
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print("Server JsonObject response: \(json)")
                    
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // decodes the Server response
                guard let response = try? decoder.decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data) else {
                    print("Something happen here")
                    completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                    return
                }
                
                // Returns if an error occurs
                if let error = response.errors {
                    completion(.failure(AppError.serverError(error)))
                    return
                }
                // Decodes the data received from server
                if let decodedData = response.results {
                    completion(.success(decodedData as! T))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help me understand why my code isnt working that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It'll be easier to give you a response if you include in your question what error you are seeing!

Comment: Read the JSON carefully. Already the first key doesn’t match the struct. And you can help yourself if you don’t ignore decoding errors and if you don’t declare everything carelessly as optional.

Comment: Use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` inside `catch` instead of `try?` when you're decoding. Then you can at least get a meaningful error.

Comment: "why my code does not work"  How doesn't it work?

Comment: @idz the error I am receiving is from a custom error struct that I made basically telling me that it was unable to decode. To be more clear, my question is how can I properly decode the json data I am receiving. I have little experience in swift or app development as well as working with json data

Comment: @vadian Im new to swift and app development so this is all a learning experience for me.

Comment: @ElTomato terrible communication on my part. My question is basically how can I properly decode the json data into a useable struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct is wrong. Try using this?

```
struct YourAPIData {
 struct Root: Codable {
    struct Result: Codable {
        struct Login: Codable {
            let isAuthorized: Bool
            let isEmpty: Bool
            struct UserName: Codable {
                let isEmpty: Bool
                struct Name: Codable {
                    let firstName: String
                    let lastName: String
                    let displayName: String
                    let isEmpty: Bool
                    let fullName: String
                }
                let name: Name
                let canDelete: Bool
                let id: Int
                let canModify: Bool
            }
            let userName: UserName
            let username: String
        }
        let login: Login
        struct Parameters: Codable {
            let isEmpty: Bool
            let keepLoggedInIndicator: Bool
            let username: String
            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case isEmpty
                case keepLoggedInIndicator = "keep_logged_in_indicator"
                case username
            }
        }
        let parameters: Parameters
    }
    let result: Result
    let isAuthorized: Bool
    struct Version: Codable {
        let major: String
        let minor: String
        let fix: String
        let display: Date
        let isEmpty: Bool
    }
    let version: Version
    let isSystemDown: Bool
    let timestamp: String
    let isSuccess: Bool
 }
}
```

and try using

```
 do {
      let APIData = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourAPIData.Root.self, from: jsonData)
} catch let jsonErr { print("Error: ", jsonErr) }
```

And if you would like to display your json (for testing, i suppose?)

```
if let data = jsonData, let body = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
      print(body)
    }
  } else {
    print(error ?? "Unknown error")
  }
```

Comment: `SwiftyJSON` is not needed at all.

Comment: @vadian Oh yeah i forgot. Thanks

Comment: @Zyfe3r I recieved this - Error:  typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "version", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "display", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @KwabenaDarkwa the codable was made from the json you posted. The error specifies PRECISELY what issue you are facing. The codable has set ``Double`` for "display" but the data was in string format. So change it to string from double? 

READ THE ERROR.

Comment: @Zyfe3r Thank you